# perl subtract one month from date

Tags: perl, date

I get the dates in format %dd.%mm.%YYYY and I'm trying to substract one month, using Perl.

examples: 12.07.2013 -> 12.06.2013 , 30.09.2013 -> 31.08.2013

Should I use Date::Calc? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Subtracting one month from 30th September and ending up with 31st August would be *unusual* for a generic "take one month off" (although the reverse scenario taking one month from 31st July and ending up at 30th June, would be considered normal). Are you sure that's what is needed? Please supply a couple more examples, and any Perl code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Time::Piece`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aPiece), which is a core module since Perl v5.9.5.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime(shift, "%d.%m.%Y");
$t -= ONE_MONTH;
print $t->strftime("%d.%m.%Y");
```

Given the arguments `12.07.2013` and `30.09.2013` this code prints `11.06.2013` and `30.08.2013`, respectively.

The `strptime` function parses the string according to the template into a `Time::Piece` object. Then we can simply add/subtract to the object to manipulate the date. Here I am using a constant from the [`Time::Seconds`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aSeconds) module, corresponding to one month.

This is all taken from the documentation for [`Time::Piece`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aPiece).

Comment: `12.07.2013` minus `ONE_MONTH` equals `11.06.2013` by this method. Obviously a lot hangs on the OP's definition of *one month*, but I would expect from the examples so far, we are talking about calendar month calculations, and not a fixed number of days (or seconds).

Comment: `Time::Piece` has the `add_months` method, which would yield 12.06.2013 here (when used with `-1` as argument). However, it's still interesting what the OP expects if "impossible" dates would be the result of the operation, e.g. 30.02.2013.

Comment: @SlavenRezic `add_months` does not seem to do anything, it just produces the same date. Perhaps it is a slightly irregular function in the module.

Comment: The result of `perl -MTime::Piece -e 'warn Time::Piece->new->add_months(-1)'` is `Sat Aug 10 14:44:56 2013 at -e line 1.`. Today's 2013-09-10, so looks OK here; same result with perl 5.10.1 and 5.18.1, probably the default `Time::Piece` installed here.

Comment: @SlavenRezic Aha, I see. For some weird reason, it only returns the manipulated object, it does not affect the original object. So I would have to do `my $t2 = $t->add_months(-1)`. Well, that's original at least. Try `perl -MTime::Piece -lwe'$t = localtime; $t->add_months(-1); print $t;'`

Comment: I would not say it's original, it's just functional.

Comment: A warning: One can, indeed, get "strange" behavior, just as promised in the docs.  Taking a month off from 03-31 gives me 03-03:  `perl -MTime::Piece -wE'$d=shift//20190331; $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($d, "%Y%m%d"); say $dt; say $dt->add_months(-1)'` (and I can make it give me 02-01 as well, depending on how the date is set).  Using `ONE_MONTH` is much worse: adding a month to 05-01 that way gives me 05-31: `perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -wE'$d=shift//20190501; $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($d, "%Y%m%d"); say $dt; say $dt + ONE_MONTH'`.  Now, I do use `Time::Piece` but I have it wrapped.

Comment: [continues]  And these dates aren't unique cases, and surprises are also inconsistent.  Take a month off 07-31 (using `add_month(-1)`, the first one-liner above) and we get 07-01 -- but if use use `- ONE_MONTH` instead then we get 06-30. So in this case it is `ONE_MONTH` that gives reasonable behavior.

Answer (score 4):

[DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) supports the snap to end-of-month behavior you are looking for. The `end_of_month` option is documented in the section [Adding a Duration to a Datetime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime#dt-add_duration-duration_object). I have also provided solution for [Date::Calc](https://metacpan.org/module/Date%3a%3aCalc) which shows the logic. Output is the same for both solutions.

**[DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime):**

```
use DateTime;

my @dates = qw(
    01.01.2013
    28.02.2013
    12.07.2013
    30.09.2013
);

foreach my $string (@dates) {
    my %p; @p{qw(day month year)} = split /\./, $string;
    my $dt = DateTime->new(%p);
    for my $n (-1, 1) {
        my $res = $dt->clone->add(months => $n, end_of_month => 'preserve');
        printf "%s %+d month => %s\n", $string, $n, $res->strftime('%d.%m.%Y');
    }
}
```

**[Date::Calc](https://metacpan.org/module/Date%3a%3aCalc):**

```
use Date::Calc qw[Days_in_Month Decode_Date_EU];

my @dates = qw(
    01.01.2013
    28.02.2013
    12.07.2013
    30.09.2013
);

sub Add_Months {
    @_ == 4 || die q/Usage: Add_Months($year, $month, $day, $delta)/;
    my ($y, $m, $d, $delta) = @_;

    my $ultimo = ($d == Days_in_Month($y, $m));

    use integer;
    $m += $delta;
    $y += $m / 12;
    $m %= 12;
    if ($m < 1) {
        $y--, $m += 12;
    }
    my $dim = Days_in_Month($y, $m);
    if ($d > $dim || $ultimo) {
        $d = $dim;
    }
    return ($y, $m, $d);
}

foreach my $string (@dates) {
    for my $n (-1, 1) {
        printf "%s %+d month => %.2d.%.2d.%.4d\n",
            $string, $n, reverse(Add_Months(Decode_Date_EU($string), $n));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
01.01.2013 -1 month => 01.12.2012
01.01.2013 +1 month => 01.02.2013
28.02.2013 -1 month => 31.01.2013
28.02.2013 +1 month => 31.03.2013
12.07.2013 -1 month => 12.06.2013
12.07.2013 +1 month => 12.08.2013
30.09.2013 -1 month => 31.08.2013
30.09.2013 +1 month => 31.10.2013
```